# Wekbit qt - can't import libraries

Tags: c++, qt

I am just starting work on a browser, and I am using QT 5.8, but when i do the statement:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

into my browser.pro file, it adds nothing to the widgets box under the ui file. I just get the error Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets. please help me add the qt webkit widgets to my project! thank you!

Comment: You could add the widgets by code.

Comment: that does not work... gets the same error

Comment: You have enabled the module at the time of installing Qt ?, this does not come skill by default.

Comment: oh... thank you for this information! will try reinstalling

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: How did you install Qt?